# Disable ftp://hostname for my website

Tags: web-hosting, security

I'm hosting a page and I'm having a problem. If I write `ftp://myhostname`, the browser asks for FTP username and password and I think this may be a security problem because it doesn't happen with other websites like `ftp://google.com`.

1. Is this really a security problem?
2. If yes how to fix it.

Comment: Are you on shared hosting?? If so, then there is nothing you can do. If you have a dedicated server or some similar option, then there are things you can do.

Comment: Why would it be a security issue? Your main concern should be why FTP is enabled in the first place over SFTP. Using good TLS/SSL encryption, extra strong passwords and with something that prevents brute force attacks i.e fail2ban should be more than enough to fight off all average phishing  and attacks.

Answer (score 2):

> If I write ftp://myhostname, the browser asks for FTP username and password and I think this may be a security problem because it doesn't happen with other websites like ftp://google.com.

It can happen with numerous other URLs. What you discovered is that a server has FTP software installed and setup properly so that it allows no anonymous user access.

FTP is commonly used to transfer files (especially files that make up a website) from your computer to your server and vice-versa. SFTP is a secure version of FTP.

Without FTP, the only other common way to add files to the server is to use a web based file manager.

If you want to disable access to ftp://whatever, then you need to contact whoever has access to the applications on the server's back-end and ask that person to terminate all running FTP server processes.